# Ajax não funciona no servidor

Tags: php, javascript, html, jquery, ajax

Li algumas respostas no fórum, mas nenhuma conseguiu resolver meu problema, o Ajax funciona no local, porém quando subo simplesmente não funciona, segue o código:

```
jQuery('#formLogin').submit(function(){
    var dados = jQuery( this ).serialize();

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "script/logar.php",
        data: dados,
        success: function( data ) {
            var y = data.length;

            if (y == 9) { 
                window.location.href = "editar-perfil.php";
            }
            return false;
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: tem como passar a url do projeto?

Comment: http://aguamkt.com.br/perfil.business/login.php

Comment: Olhando o retorno da requisição aparece o seguinte erro. PHP Warning:  mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): O endereço solicitado não é válido no contexto.
 in D:\web\localuser\aguamkt\www\perfil.business\script\bd.php on line 2
Você não está conseguindo conectar no banco de dados. De uma olhada nesse arquivo db.php

Comment: Muito provavelmente você não configurou o arquivo de conexão corretamente.

Comment: Também testei, e me apareceu esse erro `POST http://aguamkt.com.br/perfil.business/script/logar.php 500 (Internal Server Error)`

Comment: Realmente, erro bobo meu, muito obrigado! Resolveu

Comment: Quando se usa `ajax` vc tem que monitorar esses "erros bobos" que você diz. Um *f12 > network* ajuda, se estiver no Chrome.